# How to remove part of a command when 'shouting'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `shout`)) {
  if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["shout perms"].includes(r.name)))
    return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");

  if (!args) {
    return;
    message.reply('Please specify a message to shout.')
  }
  const shoutMSG = args.join(" ");

  roblox.shout(groupId, shoutMSG)
    .then(function() {
      console.log(`Shouted ${shoutMSG}`);

    })
  message.channel.sendMessage(`Shouted ${shoutMSG}`)
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(`Shout error: ${error}`)
    });
}
```

Above is the code which, when the command is used, will send a shout to Roblox, However, It also shouts the prefix and command as shown below. How do I fix this and make it only shout the message not the prefix and Command?

[image]

Comment: `const shoutMSG = args.slice(1).join(" ");` presumably.

Comment: is this discord.js or roblox?

Comment: @ElectroxMortem Discord.js with the Roblox-js package.

Comment: well. I see you followed my subliminal message and marked me as correct? ;) @ScottElsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cut off the first 7 characters. 1 for the prefix. 5 for shout, and 1 more for the space

```js
var shoutMSG = '!shout Please mark this as correct'
console.log(shoutMSG)
shoutMSG = shoutMSG.substr(7)
console.log(shoutMSG)
```